# Searching for a Point within a Polygon in Morphia throws validation exception

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am using Morphia in conjunction with MongoDB. I am using the geo spatial example restaurants and neighborhoods. In particular I would like to search for restaurants (location) in a given neighborhood (Polygon).

Here is the query:

```
query.field("location")
    .within(polygon);
```

Here field "location" is a Morphia Point.The exception is:

```
Oct 13, 2017 8:04:17 PM org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper toMongoObject
SEVERE: Error converting <br> value(Polygon{exteriorBoundary=LineString{coordinates=[Point{coordinates=[-73.94732672160579, 40.62916656720943]} ... ... Point{coordinates=[-73.94732672160579, 40.62916656720943]}]}, interiorBoundaries=[]}) to reference.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toMongoObject(Mapper.java:634)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.FieldCriteria.<init>(FieldCriteria.java:64)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.FieldCriteria.<init>(FieldCriteria.java:31)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.StandardGeoFieldCriteria.<init>(StandardGeoFieldCriteria.java:30)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.FieldEndImpl.intersects(FieldEndImpl.java:161)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.FieldEndImpl.intersects(FieldEndImpl.java:1)
at com.example.mongodb.dao.impl.RestaurantDAOImpl.getRestaurantsInNeighborhood(RestaurantDAOImpl.java:47)
```